# Issue with pandas DataReader

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

I am trying the following example in python (python xy 2.7.9):

```
from pylab import *
from pandas.io.data import *
import datetime

AAPL=DataReader('GOOG','google',start=datetime.datetime(2015,1,1),\
end=datetime.datetime(2015,1,2))
```

I get the error below. Does anyone understand why this does not work, it looks like an unexpected format with the data returned? I tried with both yahoo and google as well as different tickers. I cannot find any option to ignore 'bad data' unlike with the csv reader function. Does anyone have a clue why it does not work or even better how to solve this? Thanks.

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- CParserError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 AAPL=DataReader('GOOG','google',start=datetime.datetime(2015,1,1),end=datetime.datetime(2015,1,2))
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py in DataReader(name,
>   data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause)
>        79         return get_data_google(symbols=name, start=start, end=end,
>        80                                adjust_price=False, chunksize=25,
>   ---> 81                                retry_count=retry_count, pause=pause)
>        82     elif data_source == "fred":
>        83         return get_data_fred(name, start, end)
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py in
>   get_data_google(symbols, start, end, retry_count, pause, adjust_price,
>   ret_index, chunksize)
>       439     """
>       440     return _get_data_from(symbols, start, end, retry_count, pause,
>   --> 441                           adjust_price, ret_index, chunksize, 'google')
>       442 
>       443
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py in
>   _get_data_from(symbols, start, end, retry_count, pause, adjust_price, ret_index, chunksize, source)
>       351     # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
>       352     if isinstance(symbols, (compat.string_types, int)):
>   --> 353         hist_data = src_fn(symbols, start, end, retry_count, pause)
>       354     # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
>       355     elif isinstance(symbols, DataFrame):
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py in
>   _get_hist_google(sym, start, end, retry_count, pause)
>       219                                "enddate": end.strftime('%b %d, %Y'),
>       220                                "output": "csv"}))
>   --> 221     return _retry_read_url(url, retry_count, pause, 'Google')
>       222 
>       223
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.py in
>   _retry_read_url(url, retry_count, pause, name)
>       167         else:
>       168             rs = read_csv(StringIO(bytes_to_str(lines)), index_col=0,
>   --> 169                           parse_dates=True, na_values='-')[::-1]
>       170             # Yahoo! Finance sometimes does this awesome thing where they
>       171             # return 2 rows for the most recent business day
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in
>   parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, dialect, compression, doublequote,
>   escapechar, quotechar, quoting, skipinitialspace, lineterminator,
>   header, index_col, names, prefix, skiprows, skipfooter, skip_footer,
>   na_values, na_fvalues, true_values, false_values, delimiter,
>   converters, dtype, usecols, engine, delim_whitespace, as_recarray,
>   na_filter, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines,
>   warn_bad_lines, error_bad_lines, keep_default_na, thousands, comment,
>   decimal, parse_dates, keep_date_col, dayfirst, date_parser,
>   memory_map, float_precision, nrows, iterator, chunksize, verbose,
>   encoding, squeeze, mangle_dupe_cols, tupleize_cols,
>   infer_datetime_format, skip_blank_lines)
>       463                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>       464 
>   --> 465         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       466 
>       467     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in
>   _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       249         return parser
>       250 
>   --> 251     return parser.read()
>       252 
>       253 _parser_defaults = {
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in read(self,
>   nrows)
>       708                 raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')
>       709 
>   --> 710         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
>       711 
>       712         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in read(self,
>   nrows)    1157     1158         try:
>   -> 1159             data = self._reader.read(nrows)    1160         except StopIteration:    1161             if nrows is None:
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\parser.pyd in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:7396)()
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\parser.pyd in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:7636)()
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\parser.pyd in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:8258)()
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\parser.pyd in
>   pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:8132)()
>
> C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\parser.pyd in
>   pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:20735)()
>
> CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in
>   line 15, saw 2

Comment: Please post python and pandas version, thanks

Comment: Python version is 2.7.9, pandas version 1.15.2-12

Comment: 1.15.2-12 is not a valid pandas version, what does `import pandas as pd print(pd.__version__)` show

Comment: Version 0.15.2 thanks

Comment: Well it works for me using python 3.4 64-bit and pandas 0.16.0 can you upgrade and try again?

Comment: I reinstalled the whole python package (python xy) yesterday because of this CparserError. I just upgraded to Pandas 0.16 and retried but no luck, same error message.

Comment: It's possible this is a python 2 issue, are you able to try using with python 3 version of python xy?

Comment: I don't have it installed yet but will try over the week-end

Comment: I use python 2.7.9 and pandas 0.16.0 and it works for me ... But I use vanilla python (on an Apple iMax osx machine) and not python-xy

Comment: works for me with Python 2.7.0 and pandas 0.14.1 via anaconda installation.  I suspect python xy issue?

Comment: Thank you all for trying, it looks like a firewall issue, my it guys are on jt now.